# INDEX MATCH - List with excel formula based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I need some help listing the opperations that meet a couple of criterias.

My dataset is pretty much like the following example:

```
         A           B          C         D
     -----------------------------------------  
 1  | Opp_num |  Seller_1  | Seller_2 |  Aux  |
     -----------------------------------------
 2  |  7001   |    John    |   Tom    |   1   |
 3  |  7002   |    Carl    |   John   |   0   |
 4  |  7003   |    Mary    |   John   |   1   |
 5  |  7004   |    Tom     |   Mary   |   0   |
 6  |  7005   |    John    |   Tom    |   0   |
 7  |  7006   |    John    |   Mary   |   1   |
     -----------------------------------------
```

What I really need is to list all the operations where "John" appears either in column "seller_1" or "seller_2", and also column "Aux" is equal to 1.

In this example the listed operations should be:

```
7001
7003
7006
```

I have tried a couple of things with no success.
Thanks in advance for your help!
MD

Comment: Can you create a fifth column containing the logic in the answer below, then use the excel filter to list just those where the value is "True"?

Comment: Th question is intended to accomplish the requirements of a consolidated dashboard. I need to list the operations in a determined seccion. I simplified the scheme so people could understand what I was looking for. I already have ths formula =IFERROR(IF(D246="";"";INDEX('Informe Rentabilidad de Negocio'!C:C;MATCH(0;IF($C$337='Informe Rentabilidad de Negocio'!AF:AF;COUNTIF($D$245:D246;'Informe Rentabilidad de Negocio'!C:C);IF($C$337='Informe Rentabilidad de Negocio'!AJ:AJ;COUNTIF($D$245:D246;'Informe Rentabilidad de Negocio'!C:C))); 0)));"") but I need to include the criteria "aux=1" also in it.

Comment: Well, have you thought about using a Pivot Table? That's the kind of thing they do.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(D2=1,OR(C2="John",B2="John")),A2,"")

Here it is. Paste it in the cell.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your answer, but I need them to be listed without spaces. Any clue?